# refcount + unresolved cross references + ~ 100 runs of pdflatex

Tags: cross-referencing, pdftex, auxiliary-files

Is there anybody out there, with an idea how to speed things up? I need to run `pdflatex` ~ 100 times because of unresolved cross references.

I use `refcount` to add a number to each row of a table (list of requirements) to refer to it later on (Req. 1, Req. 2, ...) . I wrapped it in the following module:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{tabrowcounter}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
\let\rc@refused\refused
\makeatother
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{tab@rowcnt}{0}}
\preto\longtable{\setcounter{tab@rowcnt}{0}}
\newcounter{tab@rowcnt}
\newcommand{\tabrowno}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{tab@rowcnt}\label{#1}\setcounterref{tab@rowcnt}{#1}\arabic{tab@rowcnt}
}
\endinput
```

The number of requirements/rows is about 100. Everything works fine with one exception. I need to run `pdflatex` n - 1 times, where n is the number of requirements/rows in the table because of unresolved cross references.

I found out the following: On each run, `refcount` (or whatever component does it) adds +1 to the requirement number in `file.aux` until there are no references left (1, 2, ... , 100). I think about a workaround to solve my problem (parsing `.aux` file with a ruby script), but maybe there's a better way to do it.

Please see those the examples below:

#### `Example 1` 4 requirements

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabrowcounter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

%page 6 to distinguish between value of reference and page
\setcounter{page}{6}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{First table}
  \label{tab:num1}
  \begin{tabular}{r|r}
    \# & value \tabularnewline
    \tabrowno{ref:row1} & blub \tabularnewline
    \tabrowno{ref:row2} & blub \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\qquad
\qquad

\begin{longtable}{r|r}
  \caption{Second table}\label{tab:num2} \\
  \# & value \tabularnewline
  \tabrowno{ref:row3} & blub \tabularnewline
  \tabrowno{ref:row4} & blub \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

Reference 1 in Table \ref{tab:num1}: value \ref{ref:row1}, page \pageref{ref:row1} \\
Reference 2 in Table \ref{tab:num1}: value \ref{ref:row2}, page \pageref{ref:row2} \\
Reference 3 in Table \ref{tab:num2}: value \ref{ref:row3}, page \pageref{ref:row3} \\
Reference 4 in Table \ref{tab:num2}: value \ref{ref:row4}, page \pageref{ref:row4} \\

\end{document}
```

#### `Example 2` (5 requirements):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabrowcounter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

%page 6 to distinguish between value of reference and page
\setcounter{page}{6}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{First table}
  \label{tab:num1}
  \begin{tabular}{r|r}
    \# & value \tabularnewline
    \tabrowno{ref:row1} & blub \tabularnewline
    \tabrowno{ref:row2} & blub \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\qquad
\qquad

\begin{longtable}{r|r}
  \caption{Second table}\label{tab:num2} \\
  \# & value \tabularnewline
  \tabrowno{ref:row3} & blub \tabularnewline
  \tabrowno{ref:row4} & blub \tabularnewline
  \tabrowno{ref:row5} & blub \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

Reference 1 in Table \ref{tab:num1}: value \ref{ref:row1}, page \pageref{ref:row1} \\
Reference 2 in Table \ref{tab:num1}: value \ref{ref:row2}, page \pageref{ref:row2} \\
Reference 3 in Table \ref{tab:num2}: value \ref{ref:row3}, page \pageref{ref:row3} \\
Reference 4 in Table \ref{tab:num2}: value \ref{ref:row4}, page \pageref{ref:row4} \\
Reference 5 in Table \ref{tab:num2}: value \ref{ref:row5}, page \pageref{ref:row5} \\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But why do that `\setcounterref{tab@rowcnt}{#1}`? The number is already available as soon as you do `\refstepcounter{tab@rowcnt}`.

```
\newcommand{\tabrowno}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{tab@rowcnt}\label{#1}\arabic{tab@rowcnt}%
}
```

Comment: Great! That did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If all your table rows end with `\tabularnewline`, you should be able to patch `\tabularnewline` to increment your counter, then `\tabrowno` can just read out its current value.  That way, the number of references is computed in one pass, rather than incrementally through the .aux file.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Any good documentation where I can find something about it?